# Swift2: return a optional type object

Tags: swift, swift2, option-type

I'm new in the swift2 world and I currently struggle with a simple function :

```
// Get all moves for the first category
func getMuscles() -> BodyPart {

        let bpart:BodyPart?

        if let managedObjectContext = (UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate).managedObjectContext {
            do{
                let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "BodyPart")
                let fetchResults = try managedObjectContext.executeFetchRequest(fetchRequest) as! [BodyPart]
                bpart = fetchResults[0]
            } catch let error as NSError  {
                print(error)
                bpart = nil
            }
        }
        return bpart
}
```

[image: function in swift2]

How can I solve this issue ? And what are the 'best-practices' in swift2 for defining a function ?

Thank you

---

EDIT 1

I've tried to change the signature of the method, but error is still here :

[image]

Comment: You could just define the function to return `BodyPart?`

Comment: But then don't do this: `let muscles = getMuscles()!` Stuff to google: optional binding

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The question you should be asking yourself is whether `getMuscles()` must always return an object or if it's fine for it to return a nil.

By changing the method signature to `func getMuscles() -> BodyPart?`,
you're basically stating that a nil might be returned from that method, 
thus solving your immediate compile time issue.

In that particular context, because you're fetching objects from CoreData,
it might be wise to allow `getMuscles()` to return a nil.

The way you define your functions (if they return optionals `?`, or not) entirely depends on the calling code.

Comment: Thank you. I've updated my post (I've changed my method signature but error is still here). thank you

Comment: @johann `let bpart : BodyPart? = nil` but that will not help a lot. Remove `bpart` entirely. `return fetchResults[0]` instead of `bpart = fetchResults[0]` , inside the `catch` : `return nil`, at the end : `return nil`

Comment: Another option is changing `bpart` from a `let` to a `var`. But I'd probably jsut do what  @R Menke just described.

Comment: @Tsimmi true, glanced over that.

Answer (score 1):

Just return:

```
func getMuscles() -> BodyPart? { }
```

Answer (score 1):

Change your method signature to :
    func getMuscles() -> BodyPart?

But be careful while unwrapping the return value when the this function is being called.

Answer (score 1):

Thats nothing to do with SWIFT2.. The return type is expecting some value `BodyPart` not an optional value `BodyPart?`...But you are returning a optional value bpart

```
func getMuscles() -> BodyPart {

        let bpart:BodyPart?

      ....
        return bpart
}
```

If you want to return bpart as it is you need to create the return type as optional

```
func getMuscles() -> BodyPart? {

        let bpart:BodyPart?

      ....
        return bpart
}
```

or if you want to just return the value try this

```
func getMuscles() -> BodyPart {

        let bpart:BodyPart = ()//initialize here dont make optional

      ....
        return bpart
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I ve tried both of your code but error is still here (I ve updated my message)

Comment: you have not initialized the bpart ...instead change the let to var...and iniitalize it...if you want to  make the bpart optional